# How to make activeadmin index page decently fast?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am trying to have a basic activeadmin dashboard for a model having a large but reasonable number of objects in base (~2000)

When loading the index page, activeadmin seems to make an individual requests on all the element of the table, before selecting the 10 lines I want to display on the page, causing very long load times (~ 30 seconds).

Is there a way to improve performance ?

```
ActiveAdmin.register BatchInvoice do
    actions :all
    menu priority: 4
    config.per_page = 10

    index do
        selectable_column
        column :id
        column :dossier_id
    end
end
```

Comment: Are you specifying filters at all? your `index do` should help reduce the content, but adding filters in each model file will also speed things up a little. You'd do that in, say, app > admin > person.rb or wherever that lives (been a while since I've played with AA)

Comment: I would recommend starting with the bullet gem to make sure you don't have N+1 issues (if you haven't installed it already).

Answer (score 1):

Am not sure, but I think this might be of help: take a good look at the `== Filters` section in  `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`

```
# By default the filters include associations in a select, which means
# that every record will be loaded for each association.
# You can enabled or disable the inclusion
# of those filters by default here.
#
config.include_default_association_filters = false
```

This will require a server restart.